# 'Expected 1-3 arguments but got 0' error when doing ng build --prod

Tags: angular

I am working on a navigation panel where there is some code for hierarchy and child items coming on click of parent items:

```
 <div *ngFor="let t of temp(math.ceil(rr2.children.length/3)).fill(); let ei = index">
                        <!-- <div *ngFor="let aa of rr2.children.slice(3*ei,3*ei + 3)">t-{{aa}}</div> -->
                                    <!-- <div *ngFor="let secondChild of rr2.children.slice(3*ei,3*ei + 3); let secondChildIndex = index" class="col-md-4 text-center menu_icon" (click)="getThirdChild(secondChild,secondChildIndex)">
                                        </div>     -->
                                        <a routerLink="{{secondChild.key3}}" (click)="prevDef(secondChild, this)" *ngFor="let secondChild of rr2.children.slice(3*ei,3*ei + 3); let secondChildIndex = index" id="{{secondChild.description}}" class="col-md-4 text-center menu_icon" (click)="getThirdChild(secondChild,secondChildIndex,ei)">
                                                <i class="item_icon">{{t}}</i>    
                                                <div class="col-md-12" > {{secondChild.description}}</div>
                                        </a>

                        <!--least childs start--> <div *ngIf="showthirdChilds" id="child_row{{ei}}" class="col-md-12 third_child {{rr2.children[ei]}}">
                                <ng-container *ngFor="let er2 of selectedSecondCh">
                                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                            <a class="menu_icon" id="{{er2.description}}">
                                                <i class="item_icon_child"></i>    
                                                <div class="col-md-12">{{er2.description}}</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>


                                            </ng-container>
                                        </div>            
                    </div>
```

its giving the error: ''Expected 1-3 arguments but got 0' on the first line:
 `<div *ngFor="let t of temp(math.ceil(rr2.children.length/3)).fill(); let ei = index">`

here I am slicing the array into chunks of three, as my child elements have to come after each 3 chunks. `temp` is defined in ts file as `temp = Array;`
math is defined as: `math = Math;`

I think i am not using the 't' in `let t of temp(math.ceil(rr2.children.length/3)).fill();`.

Its working in local, but throwing error in `ng build --prod`. Please help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Typescript documentation,

> The fill method takes up to three arguments *value*, *start* and *end*.

The error appears because the method `.fill()` needs at least one argument and you have provided none. Also it is not because of your iterated item `t`.

It is bad to use `.fill()` in typescript without providing any arguments. It will result in an `undefined` value and hence leads to other errors.

[Documentation reference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.fill)